# issue in importing maven library into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to work with mahout, Installation I did according to Learning Apache Mahout Classification text book and which is successful.
I used `mvn eclipse:eclise` command but am unable to find maven in import tab according to text book I should get it. Am facing problem please some one help

Comment: Share link which you are following .

Comment: IIRC that command should create an Eclipse project through a given archetype (which Maven will download in case) and then I guess you should import / open that project within the IDE, but I agree that more informations would be helpful